# jQuery hover problem!

Tags: jquery

http://ftp.crashboxcreative.com/ftp/EastsideBaptist/EBC-Final/

I'm having a lot of trouble with a simple jquery show/hide effect.

When you hover over the slider, nav buttons fade in.  Likewise, they fadeout on mouseleave.

The problem is, they fadein/fadeout when you hover over a button!

**How can I make jQuery ignore a hover over the buttons?**

Edit: Only hover on the #slider should trigger an effect.  I'm using this plugin: http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider

I don't think the markup can be easily changed...

Comment: Would you mind clarifying which elements on your example page should cause fadeIn/Out and which shouldn't?

Comment: I just want to try to help clarify what you are describing. When you go onto the graphic slide show (slider) 2 large < and > signs appear. But when you actually move your mouse on top of the signs they disappear. Correct?

Comment: It sounds like you would like the buttons to be visible - and *not* fade in or out - when the mouse is inside the container. Is that right?

Comment: Matt: Edited.
Haydar: Yes.
Jeff:  Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons are not child elements of the slider even though they are positioned within it:

```
<div id="slider" style="overflow: hidden; width: 620px; height: 330px;">
    <div id="slider_overlay"></div>
    <ul style="width: 3100px; margin-left: -620px;"></ul>
</div>
<span id="prevBtn" style="display: none;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Previous</a>
</span>
<span id="nextBtn" style="display: none;">
```

So when your mouse enters them it's leaving `$('#slider')`, triggering the `out` callback specified here:

```
var buttons = $('#prevBtn,#nextBtn');
var hide = function () { buttons.stop(true, true).fadeOut(); }
var show = function () { buttons.stop(true, true).fadeIn(); }
$("#slider").hover(show, hide);//show/hide buttons
```

I recommend moving the previous and next buttons (spans) into the slider div, so that they are truly its children in the DOM instead of only appearing to be child elements.

**Edit**: I didn't realize the prevBtn and NextBtn spans were generated by the slider plugin, d'oh. I haven't had the chance to reivew the entire plugin code, but it looks like you might be able to get away with changing line 94 of easySlider1.7.js from

```
$(obj).after(html);
```

to

```
$(obj).append(html);
```

Since that would insert them inside the slider div. If that has undesirable side effects or it still doesn't work, you might just add this to your `$(document).ready()`:

```
$("#prevBtn,#nextBtn").hover(function() { buttons.stop(true, true).show(); });
```

Without testing it, I'm not sure if there's any flicker, but it should ensure the buttons are showing when the mouse is over them.

Comment: That's freakin' awesome.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it helps! Did you use the first or second solution? In retrospect, I realize the second solution is probably safest (at least without having reviewed the entire plugin source code). :)

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that the mouseout and mouseover events are being fired one after the other when you mouse over a button. Stick and alert inside the hide and show functions and see if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab and say that your mouse out event of the hover for your slider is firing because the < and > graphics are outside of the dive that defines slider. Have you tried putting those inside of the slider div?