# Slide between frames using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, slide

I'm trying to build a site like http://justinouellette.com/. The only problem here is I'm confused with the code. I'd like to use JQuery instead of MooTools.

Can somebody here be an angel and write up a demo? I'd like to be able to switch between frames using hyperlinks. A frame would be a  class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery plugin Cycle](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) can do this if you specify elements (like the arrow images) for the `next` and `prev` option settings.

Someone else that asked a question recently was achieved a similar effect on their site (which you can see by following [the link in their question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682482/jquery-hover-problem)) with [EasySlider 1.7](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider).

As far as occupying the entire window, you can see [in Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) that the sample site has bound a function to `window.resize`, `refigure()`, which sets the height and width of each frame to the size of the window. Translating that to jQuery should be possible - perhaps something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(refigure());
});
```

and

```
function refigure() {
    $('.frame').height($(window).height);
    $('.frame').width($(window).width);
}
```

The original code's `refigure` method is setting the dimensions of several additional elements - I think to accommodate the particular requirements of that page and possibly the code module performing the transition animations.

Comment: Here's the deal, I'd like it to be like this.

I'd have various classes, be it 'frame1', 'frame2', and 'frame3'.

'frame2' and 'frame3' would be hidden. Upon clicking a link (eg. 'next'), it'll just slide over to 'frame 2'.

Just like http://justinouellette.com.

Sorry for being rude, I came across that link you posted and didn't understand how to make it slide the entire page.

Comment: No offense taken, though I think that the business of sliding the whole page is a css issue, like o.k.w. suggests. If I have time, I'll see if I can confirm that suspicion by looking more closely at ouellette's site.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, what you want is a Carousel, there's a great JQuery Plugin called JCarousel that you can use. [Demo Here...](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. Did you take a look at the site I provided as a live closed-source demo?

Comment: using JCarousel, you can do that. Obviously, you'll need to do some work by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest out-of-the-box Jquery plugin I can find that's close to your needs:
[Step Carousel Viewer v1.8](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/stepcarousel.htm)

The details are on that page, here is what you might be interested (each frame/panel is a css class):

Sample Step Carousel HTML:

```
<div id="mygallery" class="stepcarousel">
  <div class="belt">

    <div class="panel">
      Panel 1 content here...
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
      Panel 2 content here...
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
      Panel 3 content here...
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The tricky part is how to have each panel occupy the whole page while the stepping buttons float over them. More of a CSS issue I will say. Good luck!